# SPARQL OPTIONAL rdf:rest*/rdf:first does not return the first list

Tags: sparql, graphdb

I am trying to construct a query that will return everything in an rdf list, given a specific subject.

I have a query like this:

```
PREFIX : <https://example.com/#>
PREFIX rdf: <http://www.w3.org/1999/02/22-rdf-syntax-ns#>
PREFIX sh: <http://www.w3.org/ns/shacl#>
PREFIX rdfs: <http://www.w3.org/2000/01/rdf-schema#>
select ?class ?propertyShape ?type where {
    :ClassA rdfs:subClassOf ?class .
    ?class sh:property ?propertyShape .
    OPTIONAL { ?propertyShape sh:xone/rdf:rest*/rdf:first/sh:class ?type . }
}
```

My data looks like this:

```
@prefix : <https://example.com/#> .
@prefix owl: <http://www.w3.org/2002/07/owl#> .
@prefix sh: <http://www.w3.org/ns/shacl#> .

:ClassA-shapeB
  a sh:PropertyShape ;
  sh:path :shapeB ;
  sh:nodeKind sh:IRI ;
  sh:xone (
     [
        sh:class :ClassB ;
     ]
      [
        sh:class :ClassC ;
      ]
    ) ;
.

:ClassA-shapeA
  a sh:PropertyShape ;
  sh:path :shapeA ;
  sh:nodeKind sh:IRI ;
  sh:xone (
      [
        sh:class :ClassB ;
      ]
      [
        sh:class :ClassC ;
      ]
    ) ;
.

:ClassA-shapeC
  a sh:PropertyShape ;
  sh:path :shapeA ;
  sh:nodeKind sh:IRI ;
  sh:xone (
      [
        sh:class :ClassB ;
      ]
      [
        sh:class :ClassC ;
      ]
    ) ;
.

:shapeA
  a owl:ObjectProperty ;
.

:shapeB
  a owl:ObjectProperty ;
.
:shapeC
  a owl:ObjectProperty ;
.

:ClassA
  a owl:Class ;
  a sh:NodeShape ;
  sh:property :ClassA-shapeA ;
  sh:property :ClassA-shapeB ;
  sh:property :ClassA-shapeC ;
  rdfs:subClassOf :ClassA ;
.

:ClassC
  a owl:Class ;
  a sh:NodeShape ;
.
```

The query result looks like this:

| class | propertyShape | type |
| --- | --- | --- |
| :ClassA | :ClassA-shapeB | :ClassB |
| :ClassA | :ClassA-shapeB | :ClassC |
| :ClassA | :ClassA-shapeA |  |
| :ClassA | :ClassA-shapeC | :ClassB |
| :ClassA | :ClassA-shapeC | :ClassC |

I would expect for there to also be two `:ClassA-shapeA`, having `:ClassB` and `:ClassC` like the other two, but it does not. The first `propertyShape` (alphabetically) always has it's types left out.

This query works as expected if I remove OPTIONAL, but that is needed to get the rest of the property's, (not included in this example).

Comment: First off your data does not contain any `rdfs:subClassOf` properties, so please add that to the data or remove it from the query.
Having removed it, I cannot replicate the issue on my triplestore. What triplestore are you using?

Comment: I am using graphdb. I am inferring `:ClassA rdfs:subClass :ClassA ;`. I will add that to the data

Comment: Even on graphdb I can't replicate the issue.

Comment: Are you sure the data is what you think it is?

Comment: I created a new repository using `RDF-Plus (Optimized)` as the ruleset. Imported the data by pasting directly from this post (settting the base IRI to `https:/example.com/`) pasting and running the query from this post yields the results in the table above.

Comment: I am using Graphdb 9.11.1 Free Edition